# Contacts from iCloud to Android

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-3, data-transfer

I have a Samsung Galaxy S III Android phone and need to transfer my iCloud contacts to that phone. How do I accomplish this? Can you recommend a FREE app for this or some other method, please?

Answer (score 1):

According to an [article at Maggo](http://www.maggo.info/tips-tricks-fuer-android/android-kontakte-aus-der-icloud-importieren/) (German; [Google-Translate variant](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.maggo.info%2Ftips-tricks-fuer-android%2Fandroid-kontakte-aus-der-icloud-importieren%2F)) you can use [CardDav-Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.carddav.Sync) for this:

1. start the app
2. select "Create new account"
3. fill in the settings:

   - Servername: contacts.icloud.com
   - use SSL
   - Username: your iCloud user
   - Password: your iCloud password
4. hit "Next". The app now checks the entered data
5. on the next screen, you don't need to change the Account name. Check "Sync from server to phone"
6. tap "Finish", and your contacts should be transfered from iCloud to your Android device.

[image: CardDav-Sync account data (click for larger variant)] [image: CardDav-Sync final step (click for larger variant)]
<sup>CardDav-Sync setup: Step 3 and step 5 (source: Google Play; click images for larger variant)</sup>